# Packaging libraries with .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I've made an application using both the OpenCV and WxWidgets library. The code runs fine on my development machine.

However, when I transfer it to another windows machine I get the error

```
   *"The program can't start because cv110.dll is missing from your computer.
   Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem".*
```

Now, I'm guessing installing the same versions of OpenCV and WxWidgets as used in development would resolve this problem but this is a bit much to ask of a casual 3rd party user of my code.

In my IDE (Windows Visual C++ 2008) I've linked to the relevant .lib files by going to Properties->Linker->Input

How would I go about packaging the .exe so that it works on non-development machines?
i.e. if I include the .dll files, how would I need to change the linker configuration to reflect this ? Or, can the .dll files referenced by the .lib files be incorporated into the .exe ?

Sorry, I know this issue has come up before but I can't seem to find a resolution specific to my case. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this if you've not seen it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/c3490b50-5e02-4495-bfe1-fd114516507a

Comment: @Seth Carnegie noob question -- what's a binary resource??

Comment: Something like a DLL, exe, image, whatever. Basically something that's not text.

Comment: @Seth Carnergie well if a binary resource can be a .dll then the instruction to "Put the DLL into a binary resource and use LoadResource to access it" is extremely confusing

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make sense, that guy is using the term incorrectly. See this if you haven't, it's more a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/binaryresources.aspx

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is built using dynamic libraries

The correct thing to do is create an installer containing your exe and the correct dlls you need. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285591/installer-recommendation

Comment: would it be possible to keep the dlls in a sub folder and link to them relative to the .exe, then copy and paste the folder with the subfolder?

Comment: You don't link a dll to an exe. You need the dll to be in the same folder, or somewhere on the path.  You could rewrite the opencv app to explicitly load the dlls from a specific location (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Explicit_run-time_linking) but it's not ussually necessary